# VAR model variable selection

Tags: autoregressive, vector-autoregression, omitted-variable-bias

I'm required to use two time series models in my exam project.
I want to use a stock price of an energy company, and then explain it first using ARIMA, and then adding other variables and using VAR.
My problem is that I can't find variables which pass the Granger test of causality.
I have tried prices of commodities, competitor stock prices, etc.

So now I have opted to use two of the same company's stocks, but just listed on different stock exchanges (same company, same currency - one stock trading in Germany, the other in Brussels)

Obviously, the stock on both markets is impacted by the same unobserved variables.

Is this a huge mistake, or can I proceed if I discuss and show that I am aware of omitted variable bias?

Comment: In which way do you think it could be a mistake? What variables do you think you are omitting? VAR models are often used for forecasting where omitted variable bias is of little concern, thus my question.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,Richard Hardy. The company mainly produces electricity. So, of course, using daily electricity prices for the German market could be a much more interesting variable, but it is not possible to access this data for free. And there are probably other variables that I can't think of due to lack of experience.
But thank you for clarification that omitted var. bias is not highly relevant in this case. I will proceed with what's there and keep that in mind!

Comment: Please visit https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts to merge your accounts: that will enable you to continue commenting on and editing your posts.